# Using LESS variables in HTML Data Attribute in "quotes"

Tags: css, variables, sass, less

I am currently converting code from SASS to LESS.

I have a problem with the following line of code:

```
&[data-rating = "@{counter - 0.5}"] { // THIS DOES NOT WORK
```

How can I work with variables and subtract 0.5 from my counter var and have it in a pair of quotes so that it can sit inside the HTML data attribute.

I have included two code examples so you can take the code and run it to see my results.

SASS:

```
.reviews-stars {
  display: inline-block;

  @for $i from 1 through 5 {
    &[data-rating = "#{$i}"] {
      .star:nth-child(-n + #{$i}):before {
        color: green;
      }
    }

    &[data-rating = "#{$i - 0.5}"] {
      .star:nth-child(-n + #{$i}):before {
        color: red;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

LESS:

```
.looper-review-stars(@counter) when (@counter > 0) {

  .looper-review-stars((@counter - 1)); // next iteration

  &[data-rating = "@{counter}"] { // THIS WORKS
    .star:nth-child(-n + @{counter}):before { // THIS WORKS
      color: green;
    }
  }

  // THIS DOES NOT WORK IT RETURNS THE STRING "@{counter - 0.5}"
  &[data-rating = "@{counter - 0.5}"] { // THIS DOES NOT WORK
    .star:nth-child(-n + @{counter}):before { // THIS WORKS
      color: red;
    }
  }
}

.reviews-stars {
  display: inline-block;
  .looper-review-stars(5); // launch the loop
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using a temporary variable like in the below snippet. Since selectors are strings I think it is better to keep all math operations away from it and in a separate statement.

```css
.looper-review-stars(@counter) when (@counter > 0) {

  .looper-review-stars((@counter - 1)); // next iteration

  &[data-rating = "@{counter}"] { 
    .star:nth-child(-n + @{counter}):before { 
      color: green;
    }
  }

  @temp: @counter - .5; /* temporary variable */
  &[data-rating = "@{temp}"] { 
    .star:nth-child(-n + @{counter}):before { 
      color: red;
    }
  }
}

.reviews-stars {
  display: inline-block;
  .looper-review-stars(5); // launch the loop
}
```

Comment: @Fasani Looks like this could help you.

Comment: I just decided to stop wasting my time with LESS and swapped back to SASS.